# How to receive an Intent sent by a Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have some trouble sending an Intent from a Service to an Activity. Here's the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,
MessagingActivity.NewMessageReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(XMPPService.NEW_MESSAGE);
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", body);
intent.putExtra("FROM", from);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

context is a Service
Receiver code (it's an inner class in the activity):

```
public class NewMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(XMPPService.NEW_MESSAGE))
        {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            String from = intent.getStringExtra("FROM");
            // TODO: add screen switch
            addMessage(true, from, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Android manifest entry:

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".MessagingActivity.NewMessageReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.someapp.XMPPService.NEW_MESSAGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The problem is that although the Intent is sent, onReceive() method is not called.

Thanks, Ivan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(XMPPService.NEW_MESSAGE);
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", body);
intent.putExtra("FROM", from);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the Activity

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(XMPPService.NEW_MESSAGE);


    BroadcastReceiver   mReceiver = new MessageReceiver(getApplicationContext());
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Now it crashes with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.someapp.MessagingActivity.NewMessageReceiver`. Is it because NewMessageReceiver is an inner class?

Comment: Just register a reciever in the Activtiy,